# PostgreSQL Materialized View not refreshing

Tags: postgresql, aws

I'm using PostgreSQL in DBeaver and querying data from AWS.

**ana.bookings** is a materialized view and it shows only the data up to 26th November 2018 even though all the tables and views prior to it show data from 3rd December 2018. I tried to refresh this materialized view by right-clicking refresh in DBeaver GUI. I also tried refreshing it using:

```
REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW
ana.bookings WITH DATA;
```

but it doesn't pull through the recent data. I created a view and materialized view substitutes ana.bookings2 for ana.bookings but the queries keep loading and don't show any output even if I include a limit. How can I make ana.bookings, rpt.daily_actuals and rpt.daily_performace show the latest data?

[image: Schema[1]]

SQL behind this view:

```
 CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW ana.bookings2
TABLESPACE pg_default
AS WITH credits AS (
         SELECT transactions.transaction_id,
            transactions.transaction_type,
            transactions.billing_id,
            transactions.billing_date,
            transactions.member_id,
            transactions.billing_product,
            transactions.description,
            transactions.trip_id,
            transactions.net,
            transactions.tax,
            transactions.total,
            transactions.gl_code,
            transactions.gl_description,
            transactions.vin,
            transactions.trip_date,
            transactions.trip_duration,
            transactions.trip_distance
           FROM prc.transactions
          WHERE transactions.gl_code::text = 'PROMO.FREE_DRIVING'::text
        ), usage_rev AS (
         SELECT transactions.transaction_id,
            transactions.transaction_type,
            transactions.billing_id,
            transactions.billing_date,
            transactions.member_id,
            transactions.billing_product,
            transactions.description,
            transactions.trip_id,
            transactions.net,
            transactions.tax,
            transactions.total,
            transactions.gl_code,
            transactions.gl_description,
            transactions.vin,
            transactions.trip_date,
            transactions.trip_duration,
            transactions.trip_distance
           FROM prc.transactions
          WHERE transactions.transaction_type = 'trip'::text
        ), waiver_revenue AS (
         SELECT transactions.transaction_id,
            transactions.transaction_type,
            transactions.billing_id,
            transactions.billing_date,
            transactions.member_id,
            transactions.billing_product,
            transactions.description,
            transactions.trip_id,
            transactions.net,
            transactions.tax,
            transactions.total,
            transactions.gl_code,
            transactions.gl_description,
            transactions.vin,
            transactions.trip_date,
            transactions.trip_duration,
            transactions.trip_distance
           FROM prc.transactions
          WHERE transactions.description::text = 'Collision Damage Waiver'::text
        ), grouped_rev AS (
         SELECT u.trip_id AS booking_id,
            max(u.net) AS usage_revenue,
            COALESCE(sum(c.net), 0::double precision) AS credit,
            round((max(u.net) + COALESCE(sum(c.net), 0::double precision))::numeric, 2) AS uc_revenue,
            max(wr.net) AS waiver_revenue
           FROM usage_rev u
             LEFT JOIN credits c ON c.trip_id::text = u.trip_id::text
             LEFT JOIN waiver_revenue wr ON u.trip_id::text = wr.trip_id::text
          GROUP BY u.trip_id
        )
 SELECT tr.booking_id,
    tr.booking_duration,
    tr.reservation_duration,
    tr.trip_duration,
    tr.booking_start_date,
    tr.trip_start_date,
    tr.booking_end_date,
    tr.vin,
    tr.vehicle_plate,
    tr.member_id,
    m.role AS member_type,
    t.usage_revenue,
    t.credit,
    t.uc_revenue,
    t.waiver_revenue,
    tr.distance,
    tr.start_lat,
    tr.start_lon,
    tr.end_lat,
    tr.end_lon,
    sz.name AS start_zone_name,
    ez.name AS end_zone_name,
    tr.start_pos_gis,
    tr.end_pos_gis,
    sz.zone_id AS start_zone_id,
    ez.zone_id AS end_zone_id
   FROM prc.trips tr
     LEFT JOIN grouped_rev t ON t.booking_id::text = tr.booking_id::text
     JOIN ana.members m ON m.member_id::text = tr.member_id::text
     LEFT JOIN rw.quartiers sz ON st_contains(sz.geom, tr.start_pos_gis)
     LEFT JOIN rw.quartiers ez ON st_contains(ez.geom, tr.end_pos_gis)
     JOIN billed_trips_raw bt ON bt.trip_id::text = tr.booking_id::text
  WHERE tr.booking_start_date >= '2016-09-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone AND tr.booking_end_date < ('now'::text::date - 1) AND m.test_account_p = 'f'::text
  ORDER BY tr.booking_end_date
WITH DATA;
```

Comment: Can you take dbeaver out of the equation by connecting with some other tool, like "psql" and refreshing?  It could be a dbeaver-specific bug where it never actually sends the refresh command.  Also, are you using RDS (amazon managed and tweaked flavor of PostgreSQL) , or did you install unchanged community PostgreSQL yourself on an aws instance, and what version?

Answer (score 4):

This was fixed by upgrading the AWS RDS instance and using PostgreSQL commands:

```
REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW ana.bookings;
REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW rpt.daily_performace;
```

Comment: What version of postgres does this change occur? im currently using the WITH DATA option.